# Action not mapped error using Struts 2 REST plugin

Tags: java, rest, struts2, struts-action, struts2-rest-plugin

I have written a simple code to integrate rest with Struts 2.3.24

**I have my Struts XML:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
                        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class"                      value="rest" />
    <!--  Overwrite Convention -->
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix"          value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches"   value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="com.pag.rest.service"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators"       value="service"/>
</struts>
```

**And my controller class is:**

```java
package com.pag.rest.service;
public class RequestController {

    // GET 
    public String index() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    // GET 
    public String show() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    // POST
    public String create() {
        return "Create - SUCCESS";
    }

    // PUT 
    public String update() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    // DELETE 
    public String destroy() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the service, it says not found with action not mapped exception.

Please let me know what else I need to do in order to get the code working.

Comment: Don't return `"SUCCESS"`: return `Action.SUCCESS` (the constant), or its value, `"success"`. Also don't return `"Create - SUCCESS".`. You probably need to read something about Struts2 result mapping.

Comment: Can you try changing the name of your Controller ? Because Request could somehow be a reserved word, so please try with FoobarController, just to exclude it

Comment: Did try after changing the class name , still it gives HTTP 404 .. not found error

Answer (score 0):

The parent package should be `rest-default`. Add the following constant to the configuration file `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
```

Remove

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="service"/>
```

And rename your package name to `com.pag.rest.actions`. It will search your controllers under the `actions` folder.

Comment: I did all told changes , now it is giving me error -  HTTP Status 404 - /StrutsRestProgram/request

Comment: Now it does not give Action not mapped .. that means it  is considering rest. any suggestion to get rid of this error

Comment: Do you have a jsp with the name `SUCCESS.jsp`?